Pasting filtered range not working on filtered range
I am trying to copy all visible cells from a filtered range and paste value only to the filtered cells in the column to the left although whenever there are multiple selections to copy and paste, I get a runtime error 1004: This action won't work on multiple selections. Is there any way to fix this?
Here is my code:
ws.Range("A:F").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="TBD"
LR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
ws.Columns("C").Insert
With ws.Range("B2:B" & LR)
.Offset(, 1).Formula = "=LEFT(B2,3) & ""-"" & RIGHT(B2,6)"
ws.Range("C2:C" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
ws.Range("B2:B" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
End With
ws.Columns("C").Delete

The error is occurring in this line:
ws.Range("B2:B" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)


I'm guessing you'll need to loop over the .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Areas in column C and transfer their value to the corresponding area in column B.


SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) might be nothing, add an If clause to validate the range object
PasteSpecial doesn't work on non-contiguous range
Use Offset() to simplify the destination range reference

    ws.Range("A:F").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="TBD"
    LR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Columns("C").Insert
    With ws.Range("B2:B" & LR)
        .Offset(, 1).Formula = "=LEFT(B2,3) & ""-"" & RIGHT(B2,6)"
        Dim visRng As Range, areaRng As Range
        On Error Resume Next 
        Set visRng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not visRng Is Nothing Then
            For Each areaRng In visRng.Areas
                areaRng.Value = areaRng.Offset(, 1).Value
            Next
        End If
    End With
    ws.Columns("C").Delete



Load data into an array, get it done w/o helper col

Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim arrData, rngData As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Const KEY_COL = 5 ' filter col
    Const KEY_WORD = "TDB" ' filter col
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngData = Range("A1:F" & LastRow)
    arrData = rngData.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 1 To UBound(arrData)
        If arrData(i, KEY_COL) = KEY_WORD Then
            arrData(i, 2) = Left(arrData(i, 2), 3) & "-" & Right(arrData(i, 2), 6)
        End If
    Next i
    rngData.Value = arrData
End Sub


You can get it done w/o helper col.

You could do it without the temporary column:
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim c As Range, rngVis As Range, v, ws As Worksheet, LR As Long
    
    '...
    '...
    ws.Range("A:F").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="TBD"
    LR = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    
    On Error Resume Next 'in case no visible rows
    Set rngVis = ws.Range("B2:B" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rngVis Is Nothing Then Exit Sub 'no visible rows
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For Each c In rngVis.Cells 'update visible cells directly
        v = c.Value
        c.Value = Left(v, 3) & "-" & Right(v, 6)
    Next c
    
End Sub

